# Validating a swagger

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-2.0

I am trying to validate swagger files (as part of my gradle build actually).
I have tried using [swagger-parser](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser), but while that works and gives an error if the swagger doesn't parse at all, it doesn't seem to catch issues the way http://editor.swagger.io/#/ does. (which is what I'm looking for)

Surely this is a common enough problem that there must be a way to do this already?

What I've tried:

build.gradle:

```
     compile("io.swagger:swagger-parser:1.0.31")
```

A simple swagger with some obvious issues:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  description: 'This is a sample server Petstore server.'  
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Swagger Petstore
  termsOfService: http://swagger.io/terms/
  contact:
    email: apiteam@swagger.io
  license:
    name: Apache 2.0
    url: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
host: petstore.swagger.io
basePath: /v2
paths:
  /pet:
    post:
      tags:
      - pet
      summary: Add a new pet to the store
      description: ''
      operationId: addPet
      parameters:
      - in: body
        name: body
        description: Pet object that needs to be added to the store
        required: true
        schema:
          type: '#/definitions/Pet'
      responses:
        '405':
          description: Invalid input
      security:
      - petstore_auth:
        - write:pets
        - read:pets
definitions:
  Category:
    type: petObject
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
        format: int64
      name:
        type: string
    xml:
      name: Category
  Pet:
    type: object
    required:
    - name
    - photoUrls
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
        format: int64
      category:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Category'
      name:
        type: string
        example: doggie
    xml:
      name: Pet
```

And a simple class to test it (with the intent to move this to gradle eventually) :

```
class SwaggerTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  SwaggerTest st = new SwaggerTest();
  st.validate();
}

private void validate() {
    try {

      String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("petstore.yml")));
      SwaggerParser swaggerParser = new SwaggerParser();
      SwaggerDeserializationResult result = swaggerParser.readWithInfo(content);
      swaggerParser.parse(content);

        Swagger swagger = result.getSwagger();
        if (swagger == null) {
            System.out.println("Unable to validate swagger");
        }else {
          System.out.println("Read the swagger");
        }
        List<String> messageList = result.getMessages();
        for(String message: messageList) {
            System.out.println(message);                
        }


    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error!! "+ e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

The above swagger has multiple issues, as you can see in http://editor.swagger.io/ however, swagger-parser doesnt tell me about them.

Answer (score 0):

I was running Swagger 2.0 with your file without any additional dependencies. It works without any errors, here is implementation:

```
Swagger20Parser swaggerParser = new Swagger20Parser();
```